# Is Physical interpretation of Einstein's Relativity as is widely known, a Misconception?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

My post here is to question the magical notions about the Relativity theory. There seems to be one major historic misconception in the Relativistic interpretation, commonly believed and understood to be true. [Part of the flaw stems out from the Michelson-Morley experiment, where the speed of light 'c' is measured from moving reference frame only, rather than the hypothesized ether frame]. Layman can ignore the bracketed part, without any loss to understanding this post.

Below are series of Six Points, where i will sequentially de-mystify, and present an intuitive understanding to Relativity, without much of Mathematics that goes in there.

1. Hear out my own crafted -
   "Einstein's" law of Receiving Mobile calls:
   "As you travel away from the mobile tower, calls to your mobile phone will be delayed. As you travel at speed of electromagnetic signals, calls to your mobile will stop. If at all, you manage to travel faster than electromagnetic signals, you will be able to grab the missed calls of the past." Your love might still be waiting for you
2. In Einstein's Relativity, there is a proposition that: "Time slows or time stops" at 'near c' speeds
   Bold claim, but excuse me, and tell me clearly:

What is it (A) or (B) below?

(A) Would time "appear" to have been slowed or stopped to an observer in a relative stationary frame of reference, watching the moving frame, and relying his observations purely on receipt of light signals, *or*
(B) Would time "actually" slow or stop in that moving frame, as in for a person who is moving at 'near c' speed?

3. Likewise, there is another proposition : "Length will significantly contract" at 'near c' speeds.
   What is it (A) or (B)?

(A) Would length "appear" to have been contracted, while we attempt to measure it from a relatively stationary frame of reference, using a light signal based measurement system? *or*
(B) Would length "actually" contract in that moving frame of reference, as in for a person moving in that relatively 'near c' speed frame?

4. Now, if your response to pts. (2) and (3) above, is Option "A", then it's physics and maths of light signals based measurement - nothing more to be awed at than the "Einstein's" (or read as "Pranav's") Law of Receiving mobile calls stated in pt.1.
5. However, if your response to pts. (2) and (3) above, is Option "B", and which is what most of the articles on the subject have us believe, then surely that explanation is nowhere convincingly justified - neither in the Relativity theory developed by Einstein, nor in the Michelson-Morley experiment on which the theory relies itself.
6. Regards the magical notions on time travel, in pt (2) above, doesn't Option A seem to be a "business as usual"? For example, right now here on Earth, we may be travelling at 'c' speed for some alien out there, who watching us from a telescope, might be under impression that we humans here are still an amoeba, because light signals of further evolution from our planet would, and perhaps never will reach to him or her. So much so, good or bad for the alien's observations of us! However, Option B "cunningly" leads us to believe, that if we, by any chance, manage to accelerate to a great high 'over c' speed, we could actually start travelling back to becoming an Amoeba. That's a fancy many would rave about, but justified clearly and convincingly - neither in the Relativity theory, nor in the experiment which the theory bases itself upon, none at all, whatsoever!

So be happy you are a human - here and now, traveling at about a Lakh kilometer per hour around the sun. Your time will neither slow, nor will your length contract even if you onboard on a 'near c' speed spaceship, and take a spin around the sun faster than the rest of us here on the planet. Perhaps, we may see you contracted or slowed down on your time from here in as much as the Relativistic Maths will help us project. But, to have your tea on that spaceship you will take as long worth as you did here, and your hands from your lap to your mouth, will have to extend no less than what it had to back here. Quite unlike, the fanciful interpretation of the Relativity theory!

Question: Option A or Opinion B

Regards,
Pranav, Pune, India
pensafe@gmail.com
91 9822322184

Comment: Your question has been closed, because it is essentially a question about misconceptions which are not mainstream physics and therefore not appropriate for this site. These are not your personal misconceptions, as you make clear, and I think it only fair to say that A is correct. You will find many answers on this site (including some of my own) to say so. Indeed, relativity is based on the general principle of relativity which says that the laws of physics are the same for all observers. Any contrary account should be treated as nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

1. To be clear, it is *not* possible for massive particles to travel at the velocity $c$. This isn't just a physical argument, mathematically a frame travelling at $c$ is undefined.
2. A is correct, both observers see their own clocks ticking at normal speed, what they will disagree on is what *each others* clocks read.
3. A is again correct.
4. B is wrong, see [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) and [proper length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_length).
5. This is entering *general* relativity territory, which is significantly more complicated.

These answers are something you can check right now, relative to *something* in the universe you're travelling at almost light speed, yet *your* clock from *your* perspective isn't slowed, nor are lengths near you contracted from *your* perspective.

Comment: Gravitational waves and hypothetical gravitons also travel at c.

Comment: @my2cts Thank you, updated.